# If-clause with either

Tags: conditionals

Which of these sentences look better?

In addition, if the vertices that have outedges to this vertex are more central it will also be more central.

or

In addition, if the vertices that have outedges to this vertex are more central it will be more central either.

Answer (score 1):

The first one. The second sentence is not grammatical and I have no idea what it means.

In fact, it's jarring to have "either" come at the end of a sentence without a negative inside of it. e.g. "I'm not going to watch TV and I'm not going to read a book either." "Which of the two candidates will you vote for? I personally don't like either." These are the only way you can have "either" without an "or".

Answer (score 0):

The first one.  Either indicates one of two or many choices, as in **either** *X* **or** *Y*.  In the case of your sentences, I don't see you needing "either" in there at all.

Answer (score 0):

The first is better. The use of 'either' in the second is incorrect. For maximum clarify, I suggest rephrasing the first as:

In addition, if the vertices that have outedges to this vertex are more central, the vertex (a) will also be more central (b) will be more central too.